# Get link from div and post in new link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to get a link with jquery and post this link in a new button.

Note that the new-button href needs to be added with jquery since i don't got access to the code.

My code:

```html
<div class="product-buttons">
  <a class="button-info" href="https://www.mylink.com">Link i want to copy</a>
</div>

<div class="product-price">
  <div class="price-standard">
    <span class="price-amount">
      49,00 eur
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

How i would like it to be.

```html
<div class="product-buttons">
  <a class="button-info" href="https://www.mylink.com">Link i want to copy</a>
</div>

<div class="product-price">
  <div class="price-standard">
    <span class="price-amount">
      49,00 eur
    </span>
  </div>
  <a class="new-button" href="https://www.this_is_where_i_want_the_link_above_to_appear.com">Read more</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `href` using the `attr()` and then use `append()` to insert an `a` with the desired `href` to the parent:

```js
var href = $('.button-info').attr('href');
$('.product-price').append(`<a class="new-button" href=${href}>Read More</a>`);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-buttons">
  <a class="button-info" href="https://www.mylink.com">Link i want to copy</a>
</div>

<div class="product-price">
  <div class="price-standard">
    <span class="price-amount">
      49,00 eur
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following way by using jQuery's `append()` and `attr()`:

```js
$('.product-price').append('<a class="new-button" href="">Read more</a>');
$('.new-button').attr('href',$('.button-info').attr('href'));
// To demonstrate the change
console.log($('.button-info')[0])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-buttons">
  <a class="button-info" href="https://www.mylink.com">Link i want to copy</a>
</div>

<div class="product-price">
  <div class="price-standard">
    <span class="price-amount">
      49,00 eur
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! But there is 20 products on this page. Is there any way of get the unique URL for each product?

Comment: @felsjo, Do you mean to generate unique `url` for each product?

Comment: Yes, precisely!

Comment: @felsjo, yes you can, by simply adding incremented number like `1,2,3...` to the `href`